# Why String class is not Cloneable?

Tags: java, string, clone

Why `String` class is not implementing `Cloneable` interface?

For example: (We write this type of code sometimes.)

```
String s1 = new String("Hello");

String s2 = new String("Hello");
```

Here s1!=s2;

So instead of doing this , if we could have done:

```
String s1 = new String("Hello");

String s2 = s1.clone();
```

This could be easy.

Comment: Why would it...? Why would you want to duplicate/clone an immutable object.

Comment: Just do `String s2 = s1;`. No one can break that.

Comment: If you think you really have a need for two `String` references to be different even though the values might be the same, I'd suggest you rethink your design.  It probably means you're trying to do something "clever", to save a bit of typing, instead of coding what you mean.  And not only is clever code less readable, anyone who sees `s1==s2` or `s1!=s2` in your code will probably think you made a newbie mistake.

Comment: It seems that this may be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe instead of asking about `s1.clone();` explain why do you need separate instance of immutable object?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ,but this will copy the reference ,not the content .

Comment: @SteveL Why does that matter? In this case?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ,he wants it to be  s1!=s2 ,thats the point of the question

Comment: @SteveL Right. And we've established there's no point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String` class represents an immutable string.  There would be no purpose to cloning a `String`.  If you feel that you need to clone it, then you can just reuse the same reference and achieve the same effect.

Even if you could `clone` `s1` as `s2`, then `s1 != s2` would still be `true`.  They'd still be references to distinct objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone string with

```
String clonedString = new String(stringToClone);
```

so

```
String s1 = new String("Hello");
String s2 = new String(s1);
```

Comment: But see the other answers:  If your solution requires you to clone an immutable object, then your solution probably is some kind of a sneaky/clever trick that will be hard for other programmers to understand.  That's almost always a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
String s2 = s1.concat("");
```