# What prevents from making Cloneable a mutable object like StringBuilder?

Tags: java, clone, stringbuilder, stringbuffer, cloneable

It is a bad idea to make an *immutable* object `Cloneable`. [This is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488506/why-string-class-is-not-cloneable) `String` is not Cloneable. Immutable `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` are also *not* `Cloneable`.

But mutable **StringBuilder and StringBuffer cannot be cloned!**

What is the reason behind that desicion?

Yes, I can use "copy constructor" `new StringBuilder(CharSequence seq)` but *what is the design principle/reasoning to supply a copy constructor and prohibit cloning*?

Comment: Whilst the question isn't a direct dupe, the quotes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34123774/3788176) is relevant: TL;DR: the design of `Cloneable` is pretty flawed.

Comment: @AndyTurner I remembered I answered something like this some time ago :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `Cloneable` was mistake from beginning.

- It have difficult to use interface (you have to cast result back)
- Unclean semantic (will it be deep clone or shallow clone?)
- It is difficult to customize

All of these made this interface unpopular.

So answer is: **no one wants it**.

**EDIT**

If you want to know why it will be bad idea to implement `Cloneable` in `StringBuilder`: `Cloneable` have shallow-copy semantic and this make difficult to maintain invariants (this is generic problem with shallow copy of mutable objects). For example there is optimizations in `toString` which will be broken in case we clone it.